# Using Microsoft Graph to obtain Access Token for Azure Web App Continuous Integration Deployment

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-sdk-.net, azure-fluent-api

I am attempting to wire up source control with continuous integration to an Azure Web App programmatically via C#. Historically I've used Azure PowerShell to do the same.

On the C# side, I am using the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent libraries. The code to wire up source control is pretty straight forward:

```
await webApp.Update().DefineSourceControl().WithContinuouslyIntegratedGitHubRepository(GIT_URL).WithBranch(GIT_BRANCH).WithGitHubAccessToken(GIT_TOKEN).Attach().ApplyAsync();
```

This code runs for about 5 minutes and then returns the error:

> {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Parameter x-ms-client-principal-name
> is null or empty."}

I initially interpreted this to mean the Fluent libraries weren't passing a necessary value to the API, so I attempted to hit the API directly using Fluent libraries to abstract the authorization piece:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal( CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, TENANT_ID, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var client = RestClient.Configure().WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud).WithCredentials(credentials).Build();

CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourcegroups/{RESOURCE_GROUP}?api-version=2019-10-01");
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-client-principal-name", USERNAME);
client.Credentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Several variations of this resulted in the same error referencing *x-ms-client-principal-name.* This lead me to believe the problem was with the token being used and the associated permissions. To test this, I ran the PowerShell script mentioned above, watched it run through Fiddler, and grabbed the token it used to complete. Using that token with basically the same code, it worked fine:

```
var token = "<THE TOKEN I COPIED FROM FIDDLER>";
CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(requestType, $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourceGroups/{RESOURCE_GROUP}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{WEB_APP}/sourcecontrols/web?api-version=2015-08-01");

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

if ((requestType == HttpMethod.Put || requestType == HttpMethod.Post) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(postData))
{
    request.Content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

So now, it seems to just be a matter of getting the access token myself. This is where things have become difficult. If I obtain the token as the service principal, I end up with the same *x-ms-client-principal-name* that I started with:

```
public static string GetAuthToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token");
    request.Content = new StringContent($"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&resource=https://management.azure.com", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var auth = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponse>(result);

    return auth.AccessToken;
}
```

When I attempt to obtain token using my username and password, I get an error back telling me:

> AADSTS90002: Tenant '' not found. This may happen if there are no
> active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the
> correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.

Here's the code I use for that:

```
public static string GetAuthToken(string tenantId, string username, string password, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token");
    request.Content = new StringContent($"grant_type=password&username={username}&password={password}&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&resource=https://management.azure.com", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var auth = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponse>(result);

    return auth.AccessToken;
}
```

I cannot have the C# code invoke the PS script as a work-around as it requires Azure PowerShell which is not guaranteed to be on the machine running the code (Azure Web App) and cannot be installed due to Admin restrictions.

I need to be able to obtain an access token that also has permissions for azure dev ops (formally VSTS) so I can bind/wire-up source control for continuous integration. Any guidance that can help me get past this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get it working. First, I had to create a new Azure AD User and grant it the necessary permissions; this would not work with my regular Azure Login. With the new user and permissions, I am able to successfully obtain token like so:

```
public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string clientId, string userName, string password)
{
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>");
    var resourceId = "https://management.azure.com";
    var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientId, new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password));
    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

This token then works for wiring up source control and continuous integration.